# Limitar o tempo para um input em cin

Tags: c++

Eu pesquisei um pouco sobre, mas apenas acho soluções emendadas em C, mas eu uso o C++. A dúvida é basicamente o que o título informa, se é possível limitar o tempo até que o usuário dê um input no `cin`.

```
cout << "Você tem 5 segundos para digitar algo";
cin >> input.
```

Nesse caso, se o usuário digitar algo em até 5 segundos, o input é gravado e o código segue para X lugar, caso contrário, outra coisa acontece e o código segue para Y lugar.

Comment: Crie um processo filho, através de fork(), e dispare um cronômetro que ao final encerrará o programa. Se for digitada alguma entrada no processo pai o processo encerrará o processo do cronômetro (filho).

Comment: Especificamente para C++ estude a classe thread.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você pode utilizar o **clock()** para determinar o tempo inicial, e assim que o usuário digitar algo, você pode verificar também com o clock() e determinar a diferença entre o **tempo inicial** e o **final**. Se a diferença for maior que 5 segundos, você direciona o usuário para Y.

Creio que se houver uma parada no **cin**, você não conseguirá fazer uma verificação, enquanto o usuário não entrar com os dados.

Espero ter lhe ajudado! Abraços.

Comment: **[clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) não pode ser usado para esse tipo de cálculo**, já que o mesmo retorna o tempo do programa no processador (*clock ticks*).

Answer (score 0):

Resumindo, você precisaria de uma leitura assíncrona da entrada com `std::cin`, o que não é possível.

O que acredito seja a melhor forma, é você se apoiar na biblioteca C [conio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h), específica para plataformas compatíveis com MS-DOS (por isso eu não testei o código que fiz, mas acredito que funcione):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("Pressione qualquer tecla para cancelar");
    for(int i = 20; i > 0; --i) {
        printf("\nO programa encerrara em %ds", i);
        if(kbhit()) {
            printf("\nTecla '%c' pressionada", getch());
            i = 21;
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Para opções das funções [kbhit](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit) e [getch](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch) para Linux, veja: [Linux Conio (beta)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/) ou [Using kbhit() and getch() on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux).